# Django Authorization Backends + always returning 'user.is_authenitcated' false

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Authorization Backends in order to use my own database with username and password (our own encrypted techniques).

Now when i run the sever, its giving me login button. using which i get logged in successfully. And in return i'm able to get user. Below is the code for that.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from workforce.models import GlobalUsers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from workforce.globalapiviews import hash_password

class EmailAuthBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            hashedpassword = hash_password(password)
            user = GlobalUsers.objects.get(username=username, password=hashedpassword)
            print(hashedpassword)
            if user:
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except GlobalUsers.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def get_user(self, wf_user_id):
        try:
            print(wf_user_id)
            return GlobalUsers.objects.get(pk=wf_user_id)
        except GlobalUsers.DoesNotExist:
            print(wf_user_id)
            return None
```

When comes to HTML, is always displaying 'LOGIN' button even in case of successful login.

Observed that, user.is_authenticated is always returning false.

Can any one please suggest me what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: @gogaz added the code.

Comment: What is your goal? You want to lock a specific ViewSet or you just want to do Login on the Browsable API?

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but shouldn't call `login()` too ??

Comment: `authenticate()` shouldn't return a Response

Comment: @Gregory Login on Browsable API

Comment: what's the purpose of `if user:` ? the `get` method should return one and only one record or it will raise an error, you don't need this check

Comment: @gogaz i'm just verifying wether i got user or not with the provided credentials. Yes its returning only one user at a time as username is unique in my case it returning properly.

Comment: not only one user at a time but it also raise an error if no user match or if more than one user match

Comment: @gogaz you are right, but i'm getting a user which i have seen after debuging added print.

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            hashedpassword = hash_password(password)
            user = GlobalUsers.objects.get(username=username, password=hashedpassword)
            print(hashedpassword)
            if user:
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except GlobalUsers.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

`GlobalUsers.objects.get()` raises an exception when the user is not found (it never returns None). And in that case you're returning a Response(200_OK)

`autenticate()` should raise an exception if you want to make the authentication fail or return None if you want to pass to the next Backend

Here the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

Comment: I have edited the code and verified, even its same. And i'm getting a user so it won't fall under doesnotexist case.

Comment: I don't see any code change. You're still returning a response in the exception handling, You have to return None there or raise an exception

Answer (score 0):

If locking the Browsable API to access without login is your requirement you just need to add this configuration to your settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

Then to provide an easy way to login when using the browser you can add the following to the same settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have tried this. Still same issue.

Comment: I implemented that on this repository a few minutes ago and worked perfectly ....
I commited that so you can have a look and see how it is done:https://github.com/Gpzim98/pontos_turisticos